# Start Activity and clear activity history

Tags: android, android-activity

So I have a huge maze of activities in my application. What I need to do, is that when the user logs in into the system, the activity history should be cleared. I cant just use finish() when I start a new activity, because I want the activities to have a history until the user logs in. I have experimentet with the different flags when starting an activity, but I have had no success. Any ideas?

Cheers,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I might as well reveal the hax I am currently using to solve my problem. On the "pre-logged in" activities, I have set this in the manifest:

```
android:noHistory="true"
```

Then in each activity I have this code:

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MyActivity.this, ParentActivity.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
        startActivity(intent);
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);

}
```

The FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION only works on phones with API level 5 or higher, but what it does is that instead on the "open new activity"-animation, the "going back to previous activity"-animation is played (atleast on the droid and nexus). This prevents the confusing appearence that a new activity is started when the user presses the back-button.

This solution is not perfect. On phones with a API-level lower then 5 the animations becomes incorrect. Also, it is not super neat and requires more code then I prefer. Still, it works...

Comment: This totally worked for me when trying to simulate "going back" to a previous activity (that is, of course, not really there). Thanks! I was going to accomplish this using the default animation IDs but, to my surprise, those aren't publicly available. Go figure.

Comment: if you are actually using the keyDown, you should probably return true instead of call the super

Answer (score 1):

you can use `65536` instead of `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION` for earlier versions